# How to read in an xml file in Python without node

Tags: pandas, xml, dataframe, beautifulsoup

I am trying to read in in Python this file

```
https://www.europarl.europa.eu/meps/en/full-list/xml/a
```

And I have used this code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import pandas as pd

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}
url = 'https://www.europarl.europa.eu/meps/en/full-list/xml/a'
soup = bs(requests.get(url, headers=headers).text, 'lxml')
df = pd.read_xml(str(soup))
print(df)
```

But, the result looks wrong.

```
   meps
0   NaN
```

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use intermediate libraries, [`read_xml`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_xml.html) can handle a URL:

```
df = pd.read_xml('https://www.europarl.europa.eu/meps/en/full-list/xml/a')
```

If you need to pass custom header, use `storage_options`:

```
url = 'https://www.europarl.europa.eu/meps/en/full-list/xml/a'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

df = pd.read_xml(url, storage_options=headers)
```

Output:

```
              fullName   country                                     politicalGroup      id                         nationalPoliticalGroup
0  Magdalena ADAMOWICZ    Poland  Group of the European People's Party (Christia...  197490                                    Independent
1          Asim ADEMOV  Bulgaria  Group of the European People's Party (Christia...  189525  Citizens for European Development of Bulgaria
2    Isabella ADINOLFI     Italy  Group of the European People's Party (Christia...  124831                                   Forza Italia
3      Matteo ADINOLFI     Italy                       Identity and Democracy Group  197826                                           Lega
4    Alex AGIUS SALIBA     Malta  Group of the Progressive Alliance of Socialist...  197403                               Partit Laburista
...
```

Comment: @GiampaoloLevorato you're welcome, btw, this is similar to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76564739/16343464), don't forget to read the documentations, most of the answers are already there ;)

Comment: And from the `request` output you could have used `df = pd.read_xml(io.StringIO(requests.get(url, headers=headers).text))`, no need to parse the XML (especially not with BeautifulSoup)

Comment: You are the Python God !!!!!!!!! Thank you so much ! Is there any way I can get in touch with you (and buy you a coffee)?

Comment: @Giampaolo You're welcome, happy to help. You can buy me a coffee [here](https://www.buymeacoffee.com/mozway) (and send me a message) if you like (don't feel obliged to!). Happy coding.